# CouchDB filter and pagination with views and lists

Tags: nosql, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

We are trying to build an application in HL Fabric with CouchDB and Golang, and it has grown a bit too much, and now we have many data types where we need to make join equivalents in the database to filter and display the data.

What we have tried:

Join inside the chaincode using Mango Queries, by code (doesn't seem like a good solution, but it was the only one that actually worked)
This is, get the parent, loop through results getting the children (in case of just listing)

In the case of filtering things get more complicated because we need to get the children filtered by group, get the parentIDs, use those in another query with a horrible "$or" of many IDs that we want to avoid

Join in CouchDB with views and lists

So, we came out with this "solution" but it has many problems

```
  // Collaborator document
{
  "_id": "john.doe@email.com",
  "_rev": "33-0a7f4e6f6c4a60d6ffded693ed794cb6",
  "docType": "collaborator",
  "id": "john.doe@email.com",
  "levelID": "1@level", // this is what we want to filter events by (1@level, 2@level, ...)
  "name": "John",
  "surname": "Doe",
  "~version": "CgQCAsIA"
}

// Event document
{
  "_id": "0160ca22-6ffb-40d8-a8ad-e13ce5f0a0ef",
  "_rev": "1-a23a010bcadf8b7969fb7a5aba93456a",
  "creation": "2021-04-14T14:29:34-0300",
  "docType": "event",
  "id": "0160ca22-6ffb-40d8-a8ad-e13ce5f0a0ef",
  "movement": "transfer", // we want to filter events by this field also
  "from": "jane.doe@email.com",
  "to": "john.doe@email.com", // link to collaborator document
  "quantity": 10,
  "~version": "CgQCAk4A"
}



// Our view function
function (doc) {
    if (doc.docType == "event"){
        emit([doc.creation,doc.id] , {_id: doc.id});
        emit([doc.creation,doc.id] , {_id: doc.to});
    }
}
// Our list function
function (head, req) {
  var row, last_key;
  var event, to;
  var key;
  var query = {};
  query.movement = req.query.movement;
  query.levelID = req.query.levelID;

  send('{"records" : [');
  
  while ((row = getRow())) {
    key = row.key[row.key.length-1];
    if (last_key != key) {
      if (last_key != "undefined") {
        sendJSON();
        event = undefined;
        to = undefined;
      }
      last_key = key;
    }
    if (row.doc) {
      if (row.doc.docType == "event") {
        event = row.doc;
      } else if (row.doc.docType == "collaborator"){
        to = row.doc;
      }
    }
  }
  sendJSON();
  send(toJSON({}));
  send("]}");   

  function sendJSON() {
    var pass = true;  

    if (event && to) {
      if (query.movement && event.movement != query.movement) {
        pass = false;
      }
      if (query.levelID && to.levelID != query.levelID) {
        pass = false;
      }
      if (pass) {
        event.to = to;
      }
    } else {
      pass = false;
    }
   
    if (pass) {
      send(toJSON(event));
      send(",");
    }
  }
};
   
// Then we call it with
http://127.0.0.1:5984/testchannel_huenei/_design/new_design/_list/result/events
?include_docs=true&levelID=1@level&movement=transfer
&startkey=["3000-01-01T24:00:00-0300",{}]&endkey=["1999-01-01T00:00:00-0300"]&descending=true

// And the result is something like this
{
  "records": [{
    "_id": "0160ca22-6ffb-40d8-a8ad-e13ce5f0a0ef",
    "_rev": "1-a23a010bcadf8b7969fb7a5aba93456a",
    "creation": "2021-04-14T14:29:34-0300",
    "docType": "event",
    "id": "0160ca22-6ffb-40d8-a8ad-e13ce5f0a0ef",
    "movement": "transfer"
    "from": "jane.doe@email.com",
    "to": {
      "_id": "john.doe@email.com",
      "_rev": "33-0a7f4e6f6c4a60d6ffded693ed794cb6",
      "docType": "collaborator",
      "id": "john.doe@email.com",
      "levelID": "1@level",
      "name": "John",
      "surname": "Doe",
      "~version": "CgQCAsIA"
    },
    "quantity": 10,
    "~version": "CgQCAk4A"
    },
    {}
  ]
}
```

It works, but it seems way too complicated, when with SQL it is resolved with a simple join/query. What about deeply nested documents?

We know "movement" could be filtered in the url but we actually have many other fields to filter by and as we have read, the keys have to be in order.
That means, if I have emit([doc.to, doc.movement, doc.id], null), I need to specify "to" first, that is `&startkey=[???,"transfer"]&endkey=[???,"transfer",{}]`
We tried with `&startkey=[null,"transfer"]&endkey=[\ufff0,"transfer",{}]` but it didn't work

But in any case the filtering by nested documents is the most problematic

A major problem is also that we can't paginate the results, because the keyword "limit" works only in the view and not the list

How do people solve these issues in a real Hyperledger Fabric world scenario? Or even in a plain CouchDB scenario?

Thank you

Comment: `emit([doc.active, doc.id] , {_id: doc.id});` is unnecessary bloat, since doc.id === doc._id? What am I missing?

Comment: @RamblinRose If I understand correctly, by declaring {_id: doc.id} and setting include_docs=true in the URL, CouchDB brings the document of that id

Comment: Need more information really. As stated a Parent document has a one-to-one relationship with a Child document. This confuses me with respect to both the `list` function and that `doc.id === doc._id`.  A small set of *actual* documents would help.

Comment: @RamblinRose I edited the question with more realistic examples